# Jenkins Intermittent Hangs on git clone/checkout from github on pipeline jobs

Tags: github, jenkins-pipeline

Have you seen and do you have a solution for or investigation ideas for this problem:

- jenkins pipeline jobs using Pipeline from GitHub SCM intermittently hang on clone/checkout
- nothing reported in jenkins logs about this situation
- only seems to happen when we have a lot of activity (usually right before sprint demos)
- clears after some period of time - haven't been able to detect much a pattern yet

  Checking out git git@github.com:MyTeam/myproject into 
  /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myproject-dev-deploy/workspace@script to read deploy/dev-Jenkinsfile
   git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
  Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
   git config remote.origin.url git@github.com:MyTeam/myproject # timeout=10 
  Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:MyTeam/myproject
   git --version # timeout=10
  using GIT_SSH to set credentials Deploy key for myproject
   git fetch --tags --progress git@github.com:MyTeam/myproject +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A horrible intermittent problem in a java app?  To the JVM settings we go.  Luckily CloudBees wrote a great article on this [Tuning Jenkins GC For Responsiveness and Stability with Large Instances](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/11/21/gc-tuning/)

Turns out this wasn't the prime factor.  The real cause was network configuration and impact of a backup job on saturation.  Still, an excellent article.

Here's how we debugged it:

- Github support gave us this https://github-debug.com/ script and we augmented it thus

`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo Clearing Previous Run
rm -rf /tmp/debug-repo-http
rm -rf /tmp/debug-repo-ssh

echo clone1: `date`
time git clone https://github.com/github/debug-repo /tmp/debug-repo-http

echo clone2: `date`
time git clone git@github.com:github/debug-repo /tmp/debug-repo-ssh

echo Ping: `date`
time ping -c 10 github.com

#echo traceroute: `date`
#traceroute github.com
```

- Setup jenkins job to attempt checkout, fail and report if it took longer than 30s - once via pipeline + plugin and once via shell script
- Began running various tests: dump all docker images and re-pull, s3 pull backup, s3 push backup etc.
- Repeat tests in another network area and compare results

Comment: The problem is that `git clone` isn't quite the same code as `scm checkout`.  I believe we tried testing that and while native was OK, the pipeline checkout was not.

Answer (score 0):

I had meet this issue by git clone command and it's cost me 2 days to resolved this problems.
If you run git command by **windows shell/batch** on jenkins, it maybe cause by **git ssh key issue**...

Jenkins **windows shell** or **batch command** will use '**system**' account to process git command and its ssh key setting is different form your gerrit plugin or login account.

---

### A. Different git ssh key path

The git ssh key of '**system**' account is setting in following path:

- C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.ssh
- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\.ssh

You can check ssh key in these paths for system account.

---

### B. Register key in know_host file

Jenkins will not auto import new key of known host to your know_host file.
You can do it mannually by following steps:

1. Login your local account in windows
2. [SSH](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/command/) this git remote path directly `ssh <git remote web site> -p <port>`, type yes to register the key
   [image]
3. **Copy** the registered key form local account know_host (C:\Users\.ssh) you will see the bottom of file likes:

> [gerrit.cartography.com]:29168,[10.25.174.78]:29418 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAASSSSAQABAAAAgQDPHbDKCHL3oPbzDn3qaVZR8S1EZx/rb500Th/fjQYg5jrJ7PBMVVUyNTpJ2moje5hLYjNsVtXtcoNEZjImGul2dl3f+eHrCB27X5198jr8Wj66I/xsQCLEngd7l3velsdfgd3432fsdDiFaE9INjDjgngfNzlFA+CYpFsnaorZ6XSPQ==

4. **Paste** to '**system**' know_host file.

   - C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.ssh
   - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\.ssh

I think you will resolve your problem now !
Enjoy it!